# What does "x[y]=([z]=w)" mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I am reading a bash script parsing library to under bash syntax better.

With the library, somehow I get a script as:

`x[y]=([z]=w) ls > log`

I think x[y] here is an array operation. Then what does "([z]=w)" mean?

Comment: Yes, I did not realize it was not valid until I run the assign part itself. The original line won't give an error message.

Comment: when an assignment is performed inline with a command, the assignment is only valid during the execution of the line. if you run `a=1 bash` then `echo $a` you will get 1 while inside the new bash shell but as soon as you exit the new shell you will see that `$a` will have no value. The assignment in this code (valid or not) is only available within ls but not outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man bash:

```
Arrays  are assigned to using compound assignments of the form
name=(value1 ...  valuen), where each value is of the  form  [subscript]=string.
```

for example:

```
$ declare -A foo
$ foo=([one]=1 [two]=2)
$ echo ${foo[one]}
1
$ echo ${foo[two]}
2
```

Comment: Mine is actually invalid. I did not realize the list constructor.